# How to Fix: Unable to locate element: method- XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[This is the website](https://quillbot.com/) I am trying to automate some clicks:

[image]

I have tried clicking the button using `Xpath` and `FullXpath`, but still got no luck.

This is the simple code:

```
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe',
                     chrome_options=options)

w.get("https://quillbot.com/")
time.sleep(5)
pasteXpath = "//button[contains(@class,'outlinedPrimary') and .//span[contains(text(),'Paste Text')]]"
element = w.find_element_by_xpath(pasteXpath).click()
```

But it fails with this message in the console:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="inOutContainer"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button/span[1]/div"}
```

Please show me how to automate this click using selenium.

Comment: does your xpath work in a browser on the relevant page?

Comment: try sleeping for a few seconds before attempting to get the element

Comment: Just for a sanity check, try to use outer __double__ quotes and inner __simple__ quotes for `@id='inOutContainer'`. Or put the whole XPath inside triple quotes `"""` and keep the inner double quotes

Comment: Also important to make sure the element has already been loaded into the page. You can do that using `selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait` and `selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions` very neatly and readable

Comment: Also, for me the page doesn't look like the one in the image, accessing the link you provided. First, I can't access the "Expand" option, it is disabled; second, a `Try Sample Text` button is shown in place of the `Paste Text`, though weirdly the latter appears for a moment when reloading the page, right beside the former

Comment: Tested again your code using Chrome 96.0.4664.45 on Ubuntu 20 and it works fine. There is a prompt to allow Chrome to access the clipboard, but no problem with finding the button. Have you checked your browser and driver versions?

Comment: Yes @MatBBastos , I am using the latest chromeDriver and GoogleChrome :Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: There is something about your setup that we are not able to pinpoint. Can you try the solutions in another environment?

Comment: Yeah, fixed it. I just had to explicitly switch to the new Tab after opening it. The code was executing on the old tab, so it was not working. But now, everything is fine and the solutions work great 

Comment: You were opening it in a new tab, not a new, active window? In any case, it would be nice to give feedback on the answers after solving this, since it seems to be caused by something else. Did you change your code to do what you mentioned? If yes, add it into the accepted answer, or [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```py
pasteXpath = "//button[contains(@class,'outlinedPrimary') and .//span[contains(text(),'Paste Text')]]"
element = w.find_element_by_xpath(pasteXpath).click()
```

Don't forget to add some wait / delay before it to make sure the page is fully loaded.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@class,'outlinedPrimary') and .//span[contains(text(),'Paste Text')]]"}

Comment: maybe you are missing some delay / wait before this code line to make the page loaded?

Comment: added a time.sleep(10) , is it not enough ?

Comment: Normally it's more than enough. Still having the same exception?

Comment: Yes, sir, the same exception

Comment: Can you provide (in the question, not in the comment) ALL your code?

Comment: done, please check

Comment: I see. It looks strange.. It should work

Comment: that's what iam saying sir, why your code doesn't work?

Comment: I really don't know. It should work.

Comment: I guess you will find the issue and fix the problem. Just let me know what was it caused by? I think it's not caused by what I answered

Comment: after using your suggested answer, this the error  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@class,'outlinedPrimary') and .//span[contains(text(),'Paste Text')]]"}

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using `By`, `WebDriverWait`, and `expected_conditions` in the place of `.find_element_by_xpath`.

After you click the paste button you will receive a permissions prompt. See below to get past it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import pyautogui


service = Service('C:\\Path_To_Your\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://quillbot.com/')

paste_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Paste Text']")))

paste_button.click()
time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.press('tab')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: Nice solution. Another option to avoid using `pyautogui` would be to use `selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys`, that along with `ActionChains` allows to send, press or release keys like `ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.TAB)`

Comment: @MatBBastos I have tried `selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys` with `ActionChains` and `ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.TAB)` but was not able to get it to work on this particular site.

Comment: Oh, that's unexpected. Well, then good you found another option for the answer, nice!

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException , not working buddy. I tried increasing the time to 60 secs, still getting this error

Comment: @Sainita what browser are you using? If I use Firefox the button is not displayed for me either, I had to use Chrome.

Comment: i am using Google Chrome,

Comment: @Sainita, __you__ can see the button, but the Timeout exception is being raised afterwards, that's it? Have you tried swapping the quotes, as I mentioned in the question comments?

Comment: @Mat let me try

Comment: @Sainita :  I don't see any reason why the above answer should not work.

Comment: @Jortega Time to ReOpen the _Selenium_ chatroom :)

Comment: This answer is great, but I don't want to use any keyboard function, just selenium. So, thanks for the answer anyways

Comment: [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room have ReOpened.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CSS selector instead:

```
element = w.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class*="MuiGrid-root"] > div[class="jss473"]').click()
```

You can find all the doc about css selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[class*="MuiGrid-root"] > div[class="jss473"]"}